# Sign the token payload using RSA algorithm

Tags: c#, cryptography, jwt, rsa, encode

**NOTE:** **Self signed certificate is installed on my machine.**

I have a JWT token, which I am trying to sign using RSA algorithm, I found a library "JOSE" for achieving the same with the below method.

```
Jose.JWT.Encode(payload, certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey(), JwsAlgorithm.RS256);
```

After digging into it's "Encode" method, I found that it is using `Hashing SHA-256` algorithm in it.

I am looking for a approach where hashing is excluded & directly signed by using RSA .

Any help will be appreciated !

Comment: *I am looking for a approach where hashing is excluded & directly signed by using RSA* Why? RSA message signing really only makes sense when the message is first hashed, and then the hash is signed.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Actually hashing makes sense where message/token is too long. In my case token is not so long, so i just wanted to avoid this extra overhead. please suggest any better solution so that i can directly sign it.

Comment: Libraries are designed to implement standards, and standard signing algorithms first hash the message. The cost of hashing is usually less than the cost of signing, so eliminating the hashing step doesn't save you much.

Comment: Agree with you, but still if i ask you for direct solution, can u provide?

Comment: RSA robust implementations need fixed size inputs, and the output is often padded and such. You are asking to tweak RSA, so... you could roll your own RSA signing implementation but that will highly likely be faulty (even google engineers don't do that).  
Also I'm re-iterating on @james answer: the hashing really does not degrade performance at all, when it's compared to RSA signing.

Answer (score 1):

The hash is a security requirement for most if not all signature algorithms. So you cannot exclude it.

You can however use RSA using signatures giving (partial) message recovery (as specified in ISO/IEC 9796-2) , which can return (part of) the message that has been signed. They are generally considered deprecated; if you need less signature overhead then you'd use Elliptic Curve cryptography instead.

However, which of these two you choose doesn't matter, as either one would break the JOSE / JS Web Token protocol you're trying to implement.

Comment: whole problem in short:

In my case in client side, client first has to sign the payload with it's certificate's private key and then encrypt the signed payload with my certificate's public key.

similarly, when i will get the token from the client using above mentioned technique, I'll first decrypt it using my certificate's private key and then verify the signature using client's public key.

So, in this approach hashing is not mentioned (as per my understanding). Could you please guide ?